# registering wso2 identity server admin services as REST APIs in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2

Is it possible in WSO2 API publisher to register and publish the admin services (SOAP end points) of WSO2 Identity services as REST APIs?
If possible how to do that? I tried registering one of the services but getting invalid wsdl error message. However the same wsdl is opened in browser and even I am able to make API calls to that endpoint using SOAPUI.
I am using wso2apim3.0.0.
Please suggest.

Comment: What are the steps you followed? What is the error message you got?

Comment: I have exposed the admin SOAP services in the WSO2 identity server ([admin_service.wsdl] 
enable= true) and able to view the wsdl in browser and able to make call through SOAPUi. When I provide the same wsdl url in the wso2 api manager publisher portal under SOAP endpoint registration - it gives the message "invalid wsdl url"